# Permission denied when building customized Selenium Hub and Selenium Node Chrome images

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I am trying to create a custom image for both Selenium Hub and Selenium Node Chrome but I am getting `permission denied` when running the `build` command.

What I am doing is:

1. Cloned the https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium repository;
2. Then simply run the following command on my computer `docker build -t my-chrome-image --build-arg CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=2.40 --build-arg CHROME_VERSION=google-chrome-stable NodeChrome`. Everything goes fine until I get the permission denied error.

Can anyone please help me understand what am I getting wrong? 
I've been around this for too long.

Thanks in advance!